# Is this a GET or POST request in cURL?

Tags: api, http, curl

```
curl https://api.creditcard.com/charge \ 
-H "x-apikey: API_KEY " \ 
-d email=user@host.com \ 
-d amount=9.99 \
```

It seems like a GET to me, but why would an API have a GET for charging a card? Shouldn't it be POST?

Comment: Read this: `man curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **-d** as in **post data** is passed to curl, it will do a post request. So your request will perform a post request. If you want to see more about what request curl is doing, just add **-v** for more verbose output from the request (including what http method is used).

If you want to force a type of request, just add **-XMETHOD** where METHOD can be any of the HTTP verbs (GET/POST/...).